# Comcast email client replacement

Tags: email, imap

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm looking for a comcast email client that will allow me to DELETE files on the server, but otherwise not move them from the server to the client... something like IMAP with delete capability.

The problem is that Comcrap has one of the worst email clients I've ever encountered.   It asks for confirmation of deletes regardless of keystroke combos, and it's astoundingly slow, even on a 200 Mbit internet connection.  It has to be one of the worst piles of garbage ever made for email.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

I have not played with the Comcast client much so I do not know what interface you are used to. It ran a search on the email services and it also appears that an ActiveSync connection is not available to their system. So it appears IMAP is your poison. I use eM Client as my email program and the interface is nearly the same as Outlook. The only limitation in the free version is you can only configure it for two email accounts. I think you may get hooked on it. I use LibreOffice for  all other home office processing needs. It can prove to be somewhat buggy, so for most users I recommend Google Docs as an alternative to MS Office.   Here is the link to eM Client. http://www.emclient.com/features

As well here are your IMAP Settings

```
Incoming Mail Server Name: imap.comcast.net
Incoming Mail Server Port Number:
Recommended: 993 with SSL ON
Only if Needed: 143 with SSL ON
Outgoing Mail Server Name: smtp.comcast.net
Outgoing Mail Server Port Number:
Recommended: 587 (SMTP)
Only if Needed: 465 (SMTPS)
SSL Encryption: checked
Authentication: XFINITY username and password required
```

Comment: I log into comcasts websites, and go to "email" and that's their client.  It's so gawd awful.  Filled with advertising, on a service i PAY FOR, as if they don't milk people enough.  Very few configuration options (can't ask for no prompt on delete), and others.

Comment: I see, web interfaces do not always play nice with browsers. The trouble is there are so many browsers out there these days it is not always easy to support them all. I would give eM Client a try and see how you feel about it. I can recommend a couple of others if you find it is not suitable for your preferences.

Comment: If you can get past the "never download emails" bit, Mozilla Thunderbird is an excellent desktop client that works with Comcast and other providers (Yahoo, Google, Microsoft, etc.) via IMAP - - http://filehippo.com/download_thunderbird/